# How to add android studio into rofi menu in i3wm?

Tags: linux, archlinux

I have searched everywhere, from the documentation of the rofi to add the menu item. But I cant do that. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest method is to create a shell script and add it to `/bin`.
For example create a file named android.sh with these couple of lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
sh ~/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Then search using rofi you should be able to see the listing. Don't forget to make it executible by typing `chmod +x android.sh`.

Comment: it did solve the problem. but is there any other way?

Comment: I don't know, but I have been using this method for a long time.